How does this grammar get rid of infinite recursion in left-associated recursion?
"Suppose we have a grammar like this, where alpha could be any sequence of terminals and nonterminals:
A -> A alpha | B
We can rewrite this grammar as:
A   -> B A'
A'  -> alpha A' | epsilon"
I am confused on why the epsilon is needed if it is just an empty string/token and how this grammar can remove infinite recursion in a top-down parser using left-recursion.
I have tried looking up some examples online but am having trouble finding any. I also looked at the wiki on left recursion, and it does explain it but I just dont understand the explanation.

Given input terminal B, for the original grammar G, the derivation from A is just B using the second alt of rule A -> A alpha | B. With the refactored grammar G', the derivation of B is A => B A' => B, via rule A -> B A' then 2nd alt of A' -> alpha A' | epsilon. G' allows for a top-down recursive descent implementation as the function ParseAPrime() first tests the input for alpha before calling ParseAPrime(). In this case, B != alpha, so it returns without calling ParseAPrime(). Purchase a textbook on compilers if none of this makes sense. Wiki is not enough.

Left recursion on A (infinite) is replaced with right recursion on A'.
However for parsing a sole B the following A' must parse to epsilon (empty).
The recursion of A' is not infinite, as always an alpha must be parsed in a recursion step.
Hence alpha must not be empty.
